# Can't find the runtime error -2147221080 (800401a8)

Tags: excel, vba

Please i need help for troubleshoot  this code to find if the customer in multiple sheet are exist in CUSTOMER LIST at another workbook,but i have this problem that  " automation error " is appeared while run the code

```
Sub checkcustomerID()

On Error Resume Next

Dim y As Workbook
Dim x As Workbook

Set y = ActiveWorkbook
Set x = Workbooks.Open("\\Eng_badia-pc\e\WALEED SOBEH ENGINEERING OFFICE\W-01-ADMINSTRATIVE DEPARTMENT\W-01-AD-1-SALES\W-01-D1-S1-STATMENTS\03-PROJECTS TRACKER.xlsm")

'--------------------------------------  'Inspect matching of values of multible cells in _
                                          workbook1 to row in another workbook

For i = 1 To y.Sheets.Count
For j = 1 To x.Sheets.Count

FS1 = y.Sheets(i).Range("b3").Value
FS2 = y.Sheets(i).Range("b6").Value
FS3 = y.Sheets(i).Range("e6").Value
FS4 = y.Sheets(i).Range("h6").Value
FS5 = y.Sheets(i).Range("b7").Value
FS6 = y.Sheets(i).Range("h7").Value
FS7 = y.Sheets(i).Range("e7").Value

R1 = x.Sheets(j).Range("d:d").Value
R2 = x.Sheets(j).Range("m:m").Value
R3 = x.Sheets(j).Range("n:n").Value
R4 = x.Sheets(j).Range("o:o").Value
R5 = x.Sheets(j).Range("p:p").Value
R6 = x.Sheets(j).Range("q:q").Value
R7 = x.Sheets(j).Range("r:r").Value

If FS1 = R1 And FS2 = R2 And FS3 = R3 And _
FS4 = R4 And FS5 = R6 And FS6 = R6 And FS6 = R6 Then

MsgBox "The Customer " & "" & x.Sheets(j).Range("d" & j) & "and have Customer ID:" & x.Sheets(j).Range("b" & j)

Sheets(i).Names = x.Sheets(j).Range("b" & j + 3)

Else:

MsgBox "New Customer "

End If

Next j

Next i
```

Comment: First thing to do is to tell us at which line you get the error. Note that the other Excel file has extension xlsm, which means it can run VBA code as well, and the error could really be in that code. That seems more likely as you suppress errors in the code you have put here.

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next` and try again.

Comment: And just wondering - where exactly have you seen the `:` after the `Else` like this here `Else:`. It is not wrong, but it is quite strange, thus asking :)

Comment: The row "For i = 1 To y.Sheets.Count"   give automation error sometime ,and sometime run when I debug by row F8